# normalization misses polish characters

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a big dataframe with people data. I would like to flatten all weird diacritics and convert them to the closest ascii character. Based on a solution I found in SO I do the following:

```
for column in df.columns:
            df[column] = df[column].astype("str").str.normalize('NFKD').str.encode('ascii', errors='ignore').str.decode('utf-8')
```

It works for most of the cases (haven't checked them all) however I have noticed it misses letter 'ł' in Polish. For example `Lech Wałęsa` is translated to `Lech Waesa` while my expectation would be to see `Lech Walesa`. My guess would be that it's what `ignore` parameter does in `str.encode` method. Any idea how to make it work for any  diacritic?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try using [unidecode](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Unidecode), worked perfectly for the example you described.

```
from unidecode import unidecode

for column in df.columns:
   df[column] = [unidecode(x) for x in df[column].values]
```

Comment: This worked perfectly for me. I am choosing it as the best answer because of it's simplicity.

Answer (score 8):

Look at what `normalize('NFKD')` actually does to your input string `"Lech Wałęsa"`:

```py
import unicodedata
s = "Lech Wałęsa"
print(list(unicodedata.normalize("NFKD", s)))

['L', 'e', 'c', 'h', ' ', 'W', 'a', 'ł', 'e', '̨', 's', 'a']
```

As you can see, the character 'ę' is decomposed into the letter 'e' and the diacritic '̨', but no such decomposition takes place for 'ł'. It seems that the unicode characters LATIN SMALL LETTER L WITH STROKE 'ł' and LATIN CAPITAL LETTER L WITH STROKE 'Ł' are [among the few characters](http://zderadicka.eu/removing-diacritics-marks-from-strings/) for which unicode decomposition doesn't work.

Now, when you use the output of `normalize("NFKD")` as input for `encode("ascii", errors="ignore")`, what happens is that all characters that can't be expressed as ASCII characters are silently ignored, which gives you the output `"Lech Waesa"`.

What you could do to solve this problem is to replace the exceptional 'Ł' and 'ł' manually by 'L' and 'l' before you remove the diacritics from the characters that support decomposition. You'd have to change your code like so:

```py
for column in df.columns:
    df[column] = (df[column].astype("str")
                            .str.replace("ł", "l")
                            .str.replace("Ł", "L")
                            .str.normalize('NFKD')
                            .str.encode('ascii', errors='ignore')
                            .str.decode('utf-8'))
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! I was unaware of the fact that unicode decomposition doesn't work for some characters. In my data I can expect all these characters so I would need to add a separate replace function for each of them.

Answer (score 4):

As noted in other answers, some unicode chars cannot be decomposed using the "NFKD" method. I've compiled a list of all of those chars and their equivalent normalized chars using the unicode char names.

The following code will solve your problem:

```
import unicodedata

NON_NFKD_MAP = {u'\u0181': u'B', u'\u1d81': u'd', u'\u1d85': u'l', u'\u1d89': u'r', u'\u028b': u'v', u'\u1d8d': u'x', u'\u1d83': u'g', u'\u0191': u'F', u'\u0199': u'k', u'\u019d': u'N', u'\u0220': u'N', u'\u01a5': u'p', u'\u0224': u'Z', u'\u0126': u'H', u'\u01ad': u't', u'\u01b5': u'Z', u'\u0234': u'l', u'\u023c': u'c', u'\u0240': u'z', u'\u0142': u'l', u'\u0244': u'U', u'\u2c60': u'L', u'\u0248': u'J', u'\ua74a': u'O', u'\u024c': u'R', u'\ua752': u'P', u'\ua756': u'Q', u'\ua75a': u'R', u'\ua75e': u'V', u'\u0260': u'g', u'\u01e5': u'g', u'\u2c64': u'R', u'\u0166': u'T', u'\u0268': u'i', u'\u2c66': u't', u'\u026c': u'l', u'\u1d6e': u'f', u'\u1d87': u'n', u'\u1d72': u'r', u'\u2c74': u'v', u'\u1d76': u'z', u'\u2c78': u'e', u'\u027c': u'r', u'\u1eff': u'y', u'\ua741': u'k', u'\u0182': u'B', u'\u1d86': u'm', u'\u0288': u't', u'\u018a': u'D', u'\u1d8e': u'z', u'\u0111': u'd', u'\u0290': u'z', u'\u0192': u'f', u'\u1d96': u'i', u'\u019a': u'l', u'\u019e': u'n', u'\u1d88': u'p', u'\u02a0': u'q', u'\u01ae': u'T', u'\u01b2': u'V', u'\u01b6': u'z', u'\u023b': u'C', u'\u023f': u's', u'\u0141': u'L', u'\u0243': u'B', u'\ua745': u'k', u'\u0247': u'e', u'\ua749': u'l', u'\u024b': u'q', u'\ua74d': u'o', u'\u024f': u'y', u'\ua751': u'p', u'\u0253': u'b', u'\ua755': u'p', u'\u0257': u'd', u'\ua759': u'q', u'\xd8': u'O', u'\u2c63': u'P', u'\u2c67': u'H', u'\u026b': u'l', u'\u1d6d': u'd', u'\u1d71': u'p', u'\u0273': u'n', u'\u1d75': u't', u'\u1d91': u'd', u'\xf8': u'o', u'\u2c7e': u'S', u'\u1d7d': u'p', u'\u2c7f': u'Z', u'\u0183': u'b', u'\u0187': u'C', u'\u1d80': u'b', u'\u0289': u'u', u'\u018b': u'D', u'\u1d8f': u'a', u'\u0291': u'z', u'\u0110': u'D', u'\u0193': u'G', u'\u1d82': u'f', u'\u0197': u'I', u'\u029d': u'j', u'\u019f': u'O', u'\u2c6c': u'z', u'\u01ab': u't', u'\u01b3': u'Y', u'\u0236': u't', u'\u023a': u'A', u'\u023e': u'T', u'\ua740': u'K', u'\u1d8a': u's', u'\ua744': u'K', u'\u0246': u'E', u'\ua748': u'L', u'\ua74c': u'O', u'\u024e': u'Y', u'\ua750': u'P', u'\ua754': u'P', u'\u0256': u'd', u'\ua758': u'Q', u'\u2c62': u'L', u'\u0266': u'h', u'\u2c73': u'w', u'\u2c6a': u'k', u'\u1d6c': u'b', u'\u2c6e': u'M', u'\u1d70': u'n', u'\u0272': u'n', u'\u1d92': u'e', u'\u1d74': u's', u'\u2c7a': u'o', u'\u2c6b': u'Z', u'\u027e': u'r', u'\u0180': u'b', u'\u0282': u's', u'\u1d84': u'k', u'\u0188': u'c', u'\u018c': u'd', u'\ua742': u'K', u'\u1d99': u'u', u'\u0198': u'K', u'\u1d8c': u'v', u'\u0221': u'd', u'\u2c71': u'v', u'\u0225': u'z', u'\u01a4': u'P', u'\u0127': u'h', u'\u01ac': u'T', u'\u0235': u'n', u'\u01b4': u'y', u'\u2c72': u'W', u'\u023d': u'L', u'\ua743': u'k', u'\u0249': u'j', u'\ua74b': u'o', u'\u024d': u'r', u'\ua753': u'p', u'\u0255': u'c', u'\ua757': u'q', u'\u2c68': u'h', u'\ua75b': u'r', u'\ua75f': u'v', u'\u2c61': u'l', u'\u2c65': u'a', u'\u01e4': u'G', u'\u0167': u't', u'\u2c69': u'K', u'\u026d': u'l', u'\u1d6f': u'm', u'\u0271': u'm', u'\u1d73': u'r', u'\u027d': u'r', u'\u1efe': u'Y'}

def deaccent(name):
    # Convert accented chars to their non-accented equivalent.
    # e.g.: Polynésie Française -> Polynesie Francaise
    if not isinstance(name, unicode):
        name = unicode(name)

    return ''.join(NON_NFKD_MAP[c] if c in NON_NFKD_MAP else c \
                   for part in unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', name) for c in part
                   if unicodedata.category(part) != 'Mn')

print deaccent(u"Lech Wałęsa")
```

Results in:

```
Lech Walesa
```